# What is coFrameDiv and coToolbarFrame in Chrome Inspect Element?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, code-inspection

Only recently I have noticed some extra code being adding to my page when I look at it via the Chrome Inspect Element tool. It may have been there all the time but I just noticed it.

**What is it?** Is it normal and I missed it or is a Chrome extension or is it malware?

It does not show up on my code when I view source.

**Below is the code:**

```
<div id="coFrameDiv" style="height:0px;display:none;">
<iframe id="coToolbarFrame" src="chrome-extension://
{unique-id-hiding-incase-sensitive}/toolbar/placeholder.html"
 style="height:0px;width:100%;display:none;"></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Any toolbar may be installed in chrome like Norton Toolbar. So these extra chunks of code added to your page. you can check at chrome://extensions/ if "Allow in incognito" option has not been selected for that toolbar, you will not see these extra bit of piece of code.

View source will not show dynamic generated HTML for a html, that's why it's not showing there.